# Running BIRT Viewer on Apache Tomcat on Azure

Tags: azure, tomcat, birt

I have been running BIRT Viewer in an Apache Tomcat application (Java 11, Tomcat 9.0) on Azure for a little shy of a year. It has been chugging along just fine without any issues, but abruptly my customer has informed me that it is throwing an error:

*The requested resource [/run] is not available The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.*

I tried stopping and restarting the server, but that didn't seem to change anything at all. I know this is an aging technology, but I cannot imagine why it would abruptly have stopped working. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a great answer here, but ultimately, I just created a new App Service and redeployed my stack. After that was done, it worked.